# Online SpamAssassin evaluation / RFC conformant check

Tags: email, spam, rfc, spam-prevention, spamassassin

I want to check the SpamAssassin SPAM score of E-Mails including headers generated by a script from a WebApp.

Therefore I need to run this mail through SpamAssassin to get the specific SPAM headers like:

```
Yes, score=6.032 
HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_24=1.282 
HTML_MESSAGE=0.001 
HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG=0.635 
MIME_HEADER_CTYPE_ONLY=1.996 
MIME_HTML_ONLY=1.105
RP_MATCHES_RCVD=-0.001 
SPF_PASS=-0.001 
SUBJECT_NEEDS_ENCODING=0.1
SUBJ_ILLEGAL_CHARS=1.105
T_REMOTE_IMAGE=0.01
```

One possibility could be to install SpamAssassin on the server and run it through this installation.

**Is there some online service where I can paste/send the mail to and this service gives me the SPAM headers?**

Yes, I know that you can configure SpamAssassin with different settings and therefore the SPAM score may vary from installation to installation, but a basic evaluation would help already.

**Or is there a possibility to check the RFC conformance of a message?** (Because SpamAssassin also evaluates this (eg. MIME_HTML_ONLY which means that you have no plain text content and therefore the mail isn't RFC conformant)).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here are some online resources for checking spam scores:

- http://www.port25.com/support/authentication-center/email-verification/
- http://isnotspam.com/
- http://spamscorechecker.com/
- http://spamcheck-services.com/

Or for offline checking:

- http://www.mailingcheck.com/download-spam-checker/

And here some tips to avoid False Positives: http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/AvoidingFpsForSenders

Comment: @tntu Sure it was but that doesn't mean that you have to use it... As you can see the answer helped already two other people so I don't see any reason to delete the question/answer!

Comment: Working one: http://spamcheck.postmarkapp.com/

Comment: I also use this https://dkimvalidator.com/

Comment: This is the current situation:
 - http://isnotspam.com/
These websites check mostly headers but not content:
 - https://spamcheck.postmarkapp.com/
 - https://dkimvalidator.com/
 - https://www.mail-tester.com/

Comment: One of the best tool for spam score of email is https://spamscorechecker.net/free-email-spam-score-checker

Comment: [mail-tester.com](https://mail-tester.com) is a pretty one.